# How do I merge adjustment layers

Tags: photoshop

Photoshop CS6

I got too many adjustment layers and want to merge them together to one rasterized layer.

How do I do this??

problem:
If I merge the adjustment layer with another layer, the effect of the adjustment layer goes away..

Comment: Can you post the code of the script you want to improve?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Select the first layer you want to merge, then hold Ctrl key and select the others you want to merge. Then right-click with your mouse over one of the selected layers and choose "Merge Layers"

[image]